# TouchId and FaceId authorization conditions

Tags: xcode, authorization, swift4

I need the authentication via TouchID and FaceID and various "else" requests in my app. I managed to integrate it, so that after pressing the "button" to proceed, you move on to another VIEW.

The problem is that if the "cancel" item is pressed, however, the button that is connected to the next VIEW continues to work. I would like if the user presses "cancel" it will be shown on the home page. The Button is connected via Main.Storyboard to the second VIEW Controller created.

Below is the part of the code I wrote:

```
 @IBAction func touchID(_ sender: Any){
        
        let context:LAContext = LAContext()
      
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
        {
            
            context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Autorization Required", reply: { (wasSuccessful, error) in
                
                if wasSuccessful {
                    
                    print("Correct")
                    //let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as! SecondViewController
                    
                    //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                }
                
                else
                
                {
                   print("Incorrect")
                    
                }
            })
        }else{
            
print("TouchID/Facec ID not configured")
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

Your "button" to proceed must call to your TouchID function. When you print "correct", you must create the navigation by code. If you print "Incorrect", dont create the navigation.

If you print "TouchID/Face ID not configured", you should show an alertview and maybe open the app settings configuration to enable/disable touch/faceId.